# UIViewController's view can contain another UIView object?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

There are 4 items on MyViewController.xib window:

> 1. File's Owner (of type MyViewController)
> 2. First Responder (of type UIResponder)
> 3. **View** (of type UIScrollView)
> 4. **FloatingView** (of type UIView)

Both `View` and `FloatingView` contain some controls (such as labels and text fields...), and are designed using IB. The `FloatingView` must NOT occupy the full screen; and my app functionality requires the `FloatingView` to move to a newly tapped location when user taps on the screen.

An instance variable `UIView *myFloatingView;` is defined as a property/IBOutlet and synthesized, which is connected to the `FloatingView` view on IB.

On `viewDidLoad` method, I am adding `myFloatingView` to my view controller's view as its subview as:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect myFrame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 150, 150); //initial location
    self.myFloatingView.frame = myFrame;
    [self.view addSubview:self.myFloatingView];
}
```

Apple documentation says each UIViews should have a corresponding view controller. However, I am using only one view controller here. I am treating the floating UIView object as a regular control, or say as a panel. I might in future allow user to hide/unhide this floating view.

Is this a good practice, or is there a better way (any example) to do what I am trying to do?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Its fine to do it like this. I don't think we need different view controllers for each view we create. That will be really difficult too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is fine. In fact, a viewController can often control a whole hierarchy.  Also, you said your floatingView was in the same nib as your root view? If so, you can probably make it a subview there, instead of adding as a subview in viewdidLoad.